# Set attribute of subclass in method of super class

Tags: python, oop

I have the following scenario:

```
class Baseclass(object):
    extra_fields = []
    @classmethod
    def extend(cls, key):
        cls.extra_fields.append(key)

class A(Baseclass):
    pass

class B(Baseclass):
    pass

A.extend("foo")
```

Now, `extend` of `Baseclass` will be called, setting `Baseclass.extra_fields` to `["foo"]`. Then, `A.extra_fields` will be `["foo"]`, however so will `B.extra_fields`.

Is there a way in `extend` to only modify only the subclass on which it was invoked (without defining `extend` on all subclasses, as those may not be known in advance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Baseclass(object):    
    @classmethod
    def extend(cls, key):
        if not 'extra_fields' in cls.__dict__:
            cls.extra_fields=[]
        cls.extra_fields.append(key)   

class A(Baseclass):
    pass

class B(Baseclass):
    pass

A.extend("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about defining own `extra_fields` for each subclass?

```
class Baseclass(object):
    @classmethod
    def extend(cls, key):
        cls.extra_fields.append(key)

class A(Baseclass):
    extra_fields = []

class B(Baseclass):
    extra_fields = []

A.extend("foo")
```

(You can automate that with some metaclasses magic as well.)